# Storing UICollectionViewCell state

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

How do you store the state of a UICollectionViewCell? Preferably using its indexPath.

Here's some background, and an example.

I currently have a 10x10 grid of collectionView cells. When a cell is clicked it recursively checks the surrounding cells for a specific condition using the cell's indexPath.

Here's the problem, sometimes the surrounding cells will contain the origin cell (the cell whose indexPath it is using to check for surrounding cells) causing an infinite loop. Here's an example:

Cell at IndexPath **[0, 0]** is selected, cell at [0, 0] is revealed *(I would like to store this fact)*,  and the surrounding cells are [**[0, 1]**, [1, 1], [1, 0]].

Then the recursive method checks the surrounding cells in the same way it did for the selected cell, [0, 0] - starting with **[0, 1]**. Cell at indexPath [0, 1] is revealed, and now it will be used to check for the next set of surrounding cells.

The surrounding cells for [0,1] would be [**[0, 0**], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 1]] - and this is where the problem begins/infinite loop is caused.

What is the best way to store the state of an already revealed  cell? Checking if the cell isSelected is not an option, because as you can see with [0,1], cells that haven't been selected can be checked.

I should mention that this is a custom cell - would creating a Bool in that custom cell be the best way to approach it? With a grid of 100 cells I feel like that might not be the best solution.

EDIT:

This checks surrounding cells and then makes the recursive call. The recursiveCheck is first called when a cell is selected in the didSelect method.

`````
//this checks for the nearby positions using the cell's indexpath that is being retrieved at didSelectItemAt IndexPath.
// all the variables like nearbyForLeftEdge are the different arrays that are used to know which surrounding areas to check since differnt parts of the grid have a different positions to check
func nearbyPositionsCheck(userLocation: IndexPath) -> [IndexPath] {
    var nearbyLocation = [IndexPath]()

    if edgeCases(userIndexPath: userLocation) != true && cornerCases(userIndexPath: userLocation) != true {
        nearbyLocation = idxPathsForEdges(idxPaths: nearbyCellsCoordinates, userLocation: userLocation)
    } else if edgeCases(userIndexPath: userLocation) == true && cornerCases(userIndexPath: userLocation) == false {

        if userLocation.row == 0 {
            nearbyLocation = idxPathsForEdges(idxPaths: nearbyForLeftEdge, userLocation: userLocation)
        } else if userLocation.section == 0 {
            nearbyLocation = idxPathsForEdges(idxPaths: nearbyForTopEdge, userLocation: userLocation)
        } else if userLocation.row == 9 {
            nearbyLocation = idxPathsForEdges(idxPaths: nearbyForRightEdge, userLocation: userLocation)
        } else if userLocation.section == 9 {
            nearbyLocation = idxPathsForEdges(idxPaths: nearbyForBottomEdge, userLocation: userLocation)
        }

    } else if cornerCases(userIndexPath: userLocation) == true {

        if userLocation == [0,0]  {
            nearbyLocation = idxPathsForEdges(idxPaths: nearbyTopLeft, userLocation: userLocation)
        } else if userLocation == [0,7] {
            nearbyLocation = idxPathsForEdges(idxPaths: nearbyForBottomLeft, userLocation: userLocation)
        } else if userLocation == [7,7] {
            nearbyLocation = idxPathsForEdges(idxPaths: nearbyForBottomRight, userLocation: userLocation)
        } else if userLocation == [7,0] {
            nearbyLocation = idxPathsForEdges(idxPaths: nearbyForTopRight, userLocation: userLocation)
        }

    }
    return nearbyLocation
}

func recursiveCheck(userLocation: IndexPath, cell: UICollectionView) {
    var newLocation = userLocation
    let nearbyCell = cell.cellForItem(at: newLocation) as? CustomCollectionViewCell
    let nearbyPositions = nearbyPositionsCheck(userLocation: userLocation)


    for nearby in nearbyPositions {
        if cellNumber(nearbyCells: nearbyPositions) > 0 { // cell number returns the number of surrounding cells nearby that meet the condition to stop checking for cells, which is != 0
            nearbyCell?.label.text = String(cellNumber(nearbyCells: nearbyPositions))
            nearbyCell?.backgroundColor = .green
        } else if cellNumber(nearbyCells: nearbyPositions) == 0 && nearbyCell?.isRevealed == false { //if the cell # does equal zero, call this function again until it does not.
            // in both situations I want to reveal the cell
            nearbyCell?.label.text = String(cellNumber(nearbyCells: nearbyPositions))
            nearbyCell?.backgroundColor = .cyan
            // I want to check the state of the cell before calling this. If I've already A) Selected the cell this shouldn't be checked or B)The cell has already been checked via recursion or otherwise, this shouldn't be checked
            recursiveCheck(userLocation: nearby, cell: cell)
        }
        newLocation = nearby
    }
} ````
`````

Comment: can you paste some code from where you are getting surrounding of a cell ?.... keeping a boolean will be a good solution otherwise whenever you are visiting a cell, add it into another array of "alreadyvisitedCells" so whenever you will start iterating a cell, you have to check whether same cell exist in "alreadyvisitedCells" array, if so then skip this cell to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadWaqasBhati, I'll give adding a bool a try. I've also pasted some code if you want to take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the indexPath in an NSArray when you enter the recursive method.

This method first needs to check, wether the given indexPath is already in that array or not. If yes, the method exists, because the cell has been processed already, if no it adds the indexPath to the array and goes on.